# getting RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined in express app

Tags: javascript, json, express, pug

I am getting the above error when running the following code in my express app.  When I go to localhost:3000/cards.

This is in my cards.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { data } = require('../data/flashcardData.json');
const { cards } = data;

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render('card', {
prompt: cards[0].question,
hint: cards[0].hint
 });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the code in my app.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

 app.set('view engine', 'pug');

 const mainRoutes = require('./routes');
 const cardRoutes = require('./routes/cards');

 app.use(mainRoutes);
 app.use('/cards', cardRoutes);

 app.use((req, res, next) => {
 const err = new Error('Not Found');
 err.status = 404;
 next(err);
 });

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
res.locals.error = err;
res.status(err.status);
res.render('error');
});

 app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('The application is running on localhost:3000!');
 });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Basically, I am trying to incorporate a json file into the express app and it is coming up with this error.

Comment: I think your cards controllers throws an error that has no status property and therefore express gets an undefined status. Add something like this: ```const status = err.status || 500; res.status(status);```

Comment: where shall I add that?

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set a default status in your error handler middleware if error does not contain the property status.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

const mainRoutes = require('./routes');
const cardRoutes = require('./routes/cards');

app.use(mainRoutes);
app.use('/cards', cardRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.error = err;
  const status = err.status || 500;
  res.status(status);
  res.render('error');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('The application is running on localhost:3000!');
});
```

Comment: this 
const status = err.status || 500;
helped me :) 
thanks a lot

Comment: what if err.status is something invalid (bcoz of typo) like err.status=1 or 24

Comment: Express will throw an error and send status code 500 + message + stack. If you want to send a custom response, you have 3 options: 1. wrap res.status() in try/catch, 2. use a second error middleware , 3. validate status against the builtin http.STATUS_CODES list.

Answer (score 0):

In My Case this Happened because I haven't provided Authorization in My Request :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

instead use res.render() if your are using ejs to create the template;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to have a fallback value in my custom error class like so:

```
// apiError.js
class ApiError extends Error {
  constructor(message, source, statusCode) {
    super();
    this.statusCode = statusCode || 500;
    this.message = message;
    this.source = source || 'Unknown';
  }
}
```

But the actual problem was in the custom error middleware when the response was being send:

```
// apiErrorHandler.js
import logger from '../util/logger.js';

const apiErrorHandler = function (error, req, res, next) {
  if (error.source) {
    logger.error(`${error.message} ----->  ${error.source}`);
  }

  res.status(error.statusCode ?? 500).json({ // I was missing this ?? 500 as a fallback value
    status: 'error',
    statusCode: `${error.statusCode}` ?? 500,
    stack: error.stack,
  });
};

export default apiErrorHandler;
```